# How to filter for columns using awk while keeping header line?

Tags: awk, txt

I have a file that looks like this. The file has 26 columns and ~4000 rows. I want to filter to keep the header (id to pc15) as well as filter to obtain the columns $1, $2, $12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26.

```
**id    Id  Study   Site    CancerType  Sex Country unexpected_duplicates   close_relatives genomic_sex CallPP  pc1 pc2 pc3 pc4 pc5 pc6 pc7 pc8 pc9 pc10    pc11    pc12    pc13    pc14    pc15**
468768  1032    Req Karlsruhe_VN    Breast  Female  Germany NA  NA  XX  0.999919340995249   -0.0731995  -0.0180998  -0.598532   0.0465712   0.152631    1.3425  -0.716615   -1.15831    -0.477422   0.429214    -0.5249 -0.793306   0.274061    0.608845    0.0224554
468769  1405    Req Santiago    Breast  Female  Spain   NA  NA  XX  0.999925545534076   -1.39583    -0.450994   0.156784    2.28138 -0.259947   2.83107 0.335012    0.632872    1.03957 -0.53202    -0.162737   -0.739506   -0.040795   0.249346    0.279228
468770  1564    Req Santiago    Breast  Female  Spain   NA  NA  XX  0.999935886432121   -0.960775   -0.580039   -0.00959004 2.28675 -0.295607   2.43853 -0.102007   1.01575 -0.083289   1.0861  -1.07338    1.2819  -0.132876   -0.303037   0.9752
468771  1610    Req Barcelona   Breast  Female  Spain   NA  NA  XX  0.999940022791339   -1.32007    -0.852952   -0.0532576  2.52405 -0.189117   3.07359 1.31524 0.637381    -1.36214    -0.0246524  0.708741    0.502428    -0.437373   -0.192966   0.331765
468772  RQ56001-9   Req Maastricht  Prostate    Male    Netherlands NA  NA  XY  0.999952431868993   0.13766 -0.3691 0.420061    -0.490546   0.655668    0.547926    -0.614815   0.62115 0.783559    -0.163262   -0.660511   -1.08647    -0.668259   -0.331539-0.444824
```

I have used the following command below but I get no output.

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $1,$2,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26}' PCA.covar.txt > PCA.covar2.txt
```

Can anyone help me to see what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

output

```
**id    Id  pc1 pc2 pc3 pc4 pc5 pc6 pc7 pc8 pc9 pc10    pc11    pc12    pc13    pc14    pc15**
468768  1032 -0.0731995 -0.0180998  -0.598532   0.0465712   0.152631    1.3425  -0.716615   -1.15831    -0.477422   0.429214    -0.5249 -0.793306   0.274061    0.608845    0.0224554
468769  1405    -1.39583    -0.450994   0.156784    2.28138 -0.259947   2.83107 0.335012    0.632872    1.03957 -0.53202    -0.162737   -0.739506   -0.040795   0.249346    0.279228
468770  1564 -0.960775  -0.580039   -0.00959004 2.28675 -0.295607   2.43853 -0.102007   1.01575 -0.083289   1.0861  -1.07338    1.2819  -0.132876   -0.303037   0.9752
468771  1610  -1.32007  -0.852952   -0.0532576  2.52405 -0.189117   3.07359 1.31524 0.637381    -1.36214    -0.0246524  0.708741    0.502428    -0.437373   -0.192966   0.331765
468772  RQ56001-9 0.13766   -0.3691 0.420061    -0.490546   0.655668    0.547926    -0.614815   0.62115 0.783559    -0.163262   -0.660511   -1.08647    -0.668259   -0.331539-0.444824
```

Comment: Please, note that you required _to keep the header (id to pc15)_. If you want to filter the header the same way like the columns - no predicate at all is needed: `awk '{print $1,$2,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26}' PCA.covar.txt`

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to tell us regarding the header. I assume you want it to have some kind of special treatment that's different from how you'll treat your data lines but what is that special treatment? In the expected output you SEEM to be just printing the same fields from the header line as you are from the data lines but then why mention the header line at all if you want all lines treated the same way?

Comment: The only way that `awk 'NR==1 {print $1,$2,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26}' PCA.covar.txt > PCA.covar2.txt` would produce no output is if your input file is empty so it's not clear what that part of your question is about either.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your input file is tab separated. If this is really the case then a simple `cut` command could do the job:

```
cut -f1-2,12-26 file >output
```

Answer (score 2):

did you want something like

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next;}{print $1,$2,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26}' < input.file >output.file
```

`NR==1{print;next;}` will print the first line unchanged then skip to the next input line

`{print $1,$2,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26}` will print the selected fields for the remaining lines

edit:

if you need the corresponding header to the selected fields then there is no need to do anything special on row 1

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26}' < input.file >output.file
```

Comment: It's printed the header twice

Comment: Would not that print first row, then print selected columns from header line rather than just first row?

Comment: Yes that is what it did - it printed the original header then the new header.

Comment: good spot - I have edited the answer

Comment: I am super sorry but I realised I put the original header line in output. I only want the header to be corresponding to column e.g. id    Id  pc1 pc2 pc3 pc4 pc5 pc6 pc7 pc8 pc9 pc10    pc11    pc12    pc13    pc14    pc15

Comment: ok, maybe that makes it a little simpler - see edit to the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
**id    Id  Study   Site    CancerType  Sex Country unexpected_duplicates   close_relatives genomic_sex CallPP  pc1 pc2 pc3 pc4 pc5 pc6 pc7 pc8 pc9 pc10    pc11    pc12    pc13    pc14    pc15**
468768  1032    Req Karlsruhe_VN    Breast  Female  Germany NA  NA  XX  0.999919340995249   -0.0731995  -0.0180998  -0.598532   0.0465712   0.152631    1.3425  -0.716615   -1.15831    -0.477422   0.429214    -0.5249 -0.793306   0.274061    0.608845    0.0224554
468769  1405    Req Santiago    Breast  Female  Spain   NA  NA  XX  0.999925545534076   -1.39583    -0.450994   0.156784    2.28138 -0.259947   2.83107 0.335012    0.632872    1.03957 -0.53202    -0.162737   -0.739506   -0.040795   0.249346    0.279228
468770  1564    Req Santiago    Breast  Female  Spain   NA  NA  XX  0.999935886432121   -0.960775   -0.580039   -0.00959004 2.28675 -0.295607   2.43853 -0.102007   1.01575 -0.083289   1.0861  -1.07338    1.2819  -0.132876   -0.303037   0.9752
468771  1610    Req Barcelona   Breast  Female  Spain   NA  NA  XX  0.999940022791339   -1.32007    -0.852952   -0.0532576  2.52405 -0.189117   3.07359 1.31524 0.637381    -1.36214    -0.0246524  0.708741    0.502428    -0.437373   -0.192966   0.331765
468772  RQ56001-9   Req Maastricht  Prostate    Male    Netherlands NA  NA  XY  0.999952431868993   0.13766 -0.3691 0.420061    -0.490546   0.655668    0.547926    -0.614815   0.62115 0.783559    -0.163262   -0.660511   -1.08647    -0.668259   -0.331539-0.444824
```

then

```
awk 'NR==1{print}NR!=1{print $1,$2,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26}' file.txt
```

output

```
**id    Id  Study   Site    CancerType  Sex Country unexpected_duplicates   close_relatives genomic_sex CallPP  pc1 pc2 pc3 pc4 pc5 pc6 pc7 pc8 pc9 pc10    pc11    pc12    pc13    pc14    pc15**
468768 1032 -0.0731995 -0.0180998 -0.598532 0.0465712 0.152631 1.3425 -0.716615 -1.15831 -0.477422 0.429214 -0.5249 -0.793306 0.274061 0.608845 0.0224554
468769 1405 -1.39583 -0.450994 0.156784 2.28138 -0.259947 2.83107 0.335012 0.632872 1.03957 -0.53202 -0.162737 -0.739506 -0.040795 0.249346 0.279228
468770 1564 -0.960775 -0.580039 -0.00959004 2.28675 -0.295607 2.43853 -0.102007 1.01575 -0.083289 1.0861 -1.07338 1.2819 -0.132876 -0.303037 0.9752
468771 1610 -1.32007 -0.852952 -0.0532576 2.52405 -0.189117 3.07359 1.31524 0.637381 -1.36214 -0.0246524 0.708741 0.502428 -0.437373 -0.192966 0.331765
468772 RQ56001-9 0.13766 -0.3691 0.420061 -0.490546 0.655668 0.547926 -0.614815 0.62115 0.783559 -0.163262 -0.660511 -1.08647 -0.668259 -0.331539-0.444824
```

Explanation: for first line (`NR==1`) `print` (whole line), for not first lines (`NR!=1`) `print` desired columns.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: I am super sorry but I realised a mistake in output. I want the header line to be: id    Id  pc1 pc2 pc3 pc4 pc5 pc6 pc7 pc8 pc9 pc10    pc11    pc12    pc13    pc14    pc15 - therefore corresponds to column

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- the leading/trailing `**` in the header row is OP's attempt to apply the bold setting (ie, the `**` do not exist in the file)
- no header fields contain white space and ...
- no data fields contain white space ...
- otherwise OP will need to provide details about the field separator

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
{ printf $1 OFS $2
  for (i=12;i<=26;i++)
      printf OFS $i
  printf "\n"
}
' PCA.covar.txt
```

This generates:

```
id Id pc1 pc2 pc3 pc4 pc5 pc6 pc7 pc8 pc9 pc10 pc11 pc12 pc13 pc14 pc15
468768 1032 -0.0731995 -0.0180998 -0.598532 0.0465712 0.152631 1.3425 -0.716615 -1.15831 -0.477422 0.429214 -0.5249 -0.793306 0.274061 0.608845 0.0224554
468769 1405 -1.39583 -0.450994 0.156784 2.28138 -0.259947 2.83107 0.335012 0.632872 1.03957 -0.53202 -0.162737 -0.739506 -0.040795 0.249346 0.279228
468770 1564 -0.960775 -0.580039 -0.00959004 2.28675 -0.295607 2.43853 -0.102007 1.01575 -0.083289 1.0861 -1.07338 1.2819 -0.132876 -0.303037 0.9752
468771 1610 -1.32007 -0.852952 -0.0532576 2.52405 -0.189117 3.07359 1.31524 0.637381 -1.36214 -0.0246524 0.708741 0.502428 -0.437373 -0.192966 0.331765
468772 RQ56001-9 0.13766 -0.3691 0.420061 -0.490546 0.655668 0.547926 -0.614815 0.62115 0.783559 -0.163262 -0.660511 -1.08647 -0.668259 -0.331539 -0.444824
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this command `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "} {print $1,$2,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26}' test.txt`  field separator are **space**

```
**id Id pc1 pc2 pc3 pc4 pc5 pc6 pc7 pc8 pc9 pc10 pc11 pc12 pc13 pc14 pc15**
468768 1032 -0.0731995 -0.0180998 -0.598532 0.0465712 0.152631 1.3425 -0.716615 -1.15831 -0.477422 0.429214 -0.5249 -0.793306 0.274061 0.608845 0.0224554
468769 1405 -1.39583 -0.450994 0.156784 2.28138 -0.259947 2.83107 0.335012 0.632872 1.03957 -0.53202 -0.162737 -0.739506 -0.040795 0.249346 0.279228
468770 1564 -0.960775 -0.580039 -0.00959004 2.28675 -0.295607 2.43853 -0.102007 1.01575 -0.083289 1.0861 -1.07338 1.2819 -0.132876 -0.303037 0.9752
468771 1610 -1.32007 -0.852952 -0.0532576 2.52405 -0.189117 3.07359 1.31524 0.637381 -1.36214 -0.0246524 0.708741 0.502428 -0.437373 -0.192966 0.331765
468772 RQ56001-9 0.13766 -0.3691 0.420061 -0.490546 0.655668 0.547926 -0.614815 0.62115 0.783559 -0.163262 -0.660511 -1.08647 -0.668259 -0.331539-0.444824
```

You need to change the field separator according to your input file field separator.